# OSX 10.13 Font rendering problem - Dell U3417W, ultrawide curved displays look awful.

Tags: macbook-pro, 4k, display

I realize this question has been asked before, but there seem to be about 50 different posts all offering different answers which haven't solved my issue. 
I have a 2017 Macbook Pro. I just picked up a Dell U3417W. 
My fonts look like crap. Everything is super pixelated unless i zoom my screen to about 175%. Even then, all of the text looks like it has a slight red hue around some of the letters. Is this just a result of me being used to retina display?

Prior to this i used an old 2008 Apple Cine Display. The text on that monitor wasn't retina or even 4k, but the fonts look significantly better.

I am currently using a DP to MDP cable.

Am i just stuck until someone releases a 34" 4k monitor? 
is there any way to improve the font quality now?

Thanks !